# DocFX: Generate API documentation for multiple projects

Tags: documentation-generation, xml-documentation, docfx

I'm working on a project that has multiple projects in a solution.  I would like to be able to generate the documentation from an outside directory to keep the application code folders clean.  When I try to set the src directory in my docfx.json, it doesn't seem to like absolute paths, nor does it like relative paths.

```
{
  "metadata": 
  [{
         "src": 
         [{
               "files": ["../../../Repos/Wsi.Extranet.CommonServices/Wsi.Extranet.CommonServices/**/*.csproj"]
               "exclude": 
               [
                    "**/obj/**",
                    "**/bin/**",
                    "_site/**"
               ]
        }],
        "dest": "api"
}],
"build": {
"content": [
  {
    "files": [
      "api/**.yml",
      "api/index.md"
    ]
  },
  {
    "files": [
      "articles/**.md",
      "articles/**/toc.yml",
      "toc.yml",
      "*.md"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "obj/**",
      "_site/**"
    ]
  }
],
"resource": [
  {
    "files": [
      "images/**"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "obj/**",
      "_site/**"
    ]
  }
],
"overwrite": [
  {
    "files": [
      "apidoc/**.md"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "obj/**",
      "_site/**"
    ]
  }
],
"src":    "../../../Repos/Wsi.Extranet.CommonServices/Wsi.Extranet.CommonServices",
"dest": "_site",
"globalMetadataFiles": [],
"fileMetadataFiles": [],
"template": [
  "default"
],
"postProcessors": [],
"noLangKeyword": false
 }
}
```

It says it built fine but didn't find any files and the directory that it searches for is staying in the current directory.

```
D:\temp\WsiApiDocs\docfx_project>docfx metadata
Info: Config file docfx.json found, start generating metadata...
Info: No files are found with glob pattern **/*.csproj, excluding
    **/obj/**,**/bin/**,_site/**, under directory "D:\temp\WsiApiDocs\docfx_project"
Info: Completed executing in 54.0087 milliseconds.


Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
```

When I attempt to put the relative path in the files property, I get the following:

```
D:\temp\WsiApiDocs\docfx_project>docfx metadata
Info: Config file docfx.json found, start generating metadata...
Info: No files are found with glob pattern
 ../../../Repos/Wsi.Extranet.CommonServices/Wsi.Extranet.CommonServices/**/*.csproj, 
excluding **/obj/**,**/bin/**,_site/**, under directory
 "D:\temp\WsiApiDocs\docfx_project"
**Warning: NOTE that `../` is currently not supported in glob pattern, please use `../` in `src` option instead.**
Info: Completed executing in 48.9621 milliseconds.


Build succeeded with warning.
Warning: NOTE that `../` is currently not supported in glob pattern, please use `../` in `src` option instead.
    1 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
```

So my confusion seems to be in how to use the src option instead.  If use the src in metadata, then it seems that I can't specify the file and exclusion info.  I tried to use a src property on the same level as metadata but that seemed to do nothing.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just as the error states

> `../` is currently not supported in glob pattern

`files`, `exclude` etc. use glob patterns. Set a base directory instead via `src`:

```js
{
  "metadata": [
    {
      "src": [
        {
          "files": "Repos/Wsi.Extranet.CommonServices/Wsi.Extranet.CommonServices/**.csproj",
          "exclude": [
            "**/obj/**",
            "**/bin/**"
          ],
          "src": "../../.." // <---- base directory
        }
      ],
      "dest": "api"
    }
  ],
  "content": [
    {
      "files": [
        "api/**.yml",
        "api/index.md"
      ]
    }
    // ...
  ]
}
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/mdschweda/08d82c27d392e6f0a35fbadf0d2e28e7) is an exmaple of structuring multiple projects

Comment: Awesome... thanks Marcus!.  I don't know why I was making it harder than it was.  When it said to set the base directory via src, I was thinking it was talking about the parent src node.  It didn't even enter my mind to put a child src in the parent src node.  
  
Your link to structuring multiple projects was also very helpful.

Comment: I've never seen an error message so confusing. use src... but src is an array ... no you have to guess there's an src inside the src.

Comment: I had the same problem. If it has this design, It is difficult to convince anyone in my team to use it. They laughed